# Reload PartialView from itself INSIDE

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Well,

I have a PartialView who generate a VIEW with a complex Model.
I have a button that I want to regenerate COMPLETELY my PartialView

> ```
>     @if (!Model.editFlag)
> {
> <button id="EditButton" class='btn btn-small'>Edit</button>
> }
> else
> {
> <button  class='btn btn-small'>Update</button>
> }
> ```

This is my Ajax CALL

```
    $.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("DeviceDetails_Edit","DeviceLayout")"  ,
    data:
    {
        DeviceID: '@Model.DeviceID',
        DeviceName: '@Model.DeviceName',
        DeviceDescription: '@Model.DeviceDescription',
        editFlag: '@Model.editFlag',
    },
    cache:false,
    success: function(html) 
        { 
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function(e) 
            { 
            alert("errorn"); 
            }

});
});
```

and from controller, I have an ActionResult , who returns a partial view with MY NEW SPECIFIC MODEL
return PartialView("_DeviceDetails", model);

Into My view , exists more more PartialView`s

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: What you mean when you said: "into my view, exists more more partialViews's" and what is the problem or error?

Comment: Is not important this aspect (that I have more PartialView`s in my page) , what I want is to reload completely my partial view from another action when I press a button

Comment: Thanks Felipe Oriani !

Comment: Remember to check my answer is it help you :)

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you already have a div on your page. With jQuery, you can clear a `div` element in your click event button, for sample

```
<div id="myView"></div>
```

With jquery, you can clear the div with `empty` method:

```
$("button").click (function (e) {

   // clear the html on the  div
   $("#myDiv").empty();


    // make a post to reload the div:
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("DeviceDetails_Edit","DeviceLayout")"  ,
        data:
        {
            DeviceID: '@Model.DeviceID',
            DeviceName: '@Model.DeviceName',
            DeviceDescription: '@Model.DeviceDescription',
            editFlag: '@Model.editFlag',
        },
        cache:false,
        success:function(html) 
                { 
                    // fill the div with the html returned by action
                    $("#myView").html(html);
                },
        error:  function(e) 
                { 
                    alert("errorn"); 
                }
    });   

});
```

Comment: It is outside view. But how to reload partial view from that partial view?

Comment: Add a javascript inside this partial view to load another one. Take  a look at javascript (jquery) code.